# Limit Processing To Certain Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that on one click changes the cell colour to amber, on two green, right click back to white.

This affects the whole sheet. I only want it in cells b2 to b1000.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    Case 45: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Sub
```

Comment: [Application.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect).

Comment: Have you checked that the `Target` parameter passed in is set appropriately?

Comment: Im sorry guys I'm not very good with sort of thing I remember I managed it years ago by finding other peoples code and just pasting it all together but technically i have no idea on how any of this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Comintern suggested, the trick is to see if the clicked cell (Target) and the range b2:b1000 intersect, and only run if they do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("b2:b1000")) Is Nothing Then
Cancel = True
Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    Case 45: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Select
end if
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm Honestly so lost aha sorry mate i'm really out of my depth here as simple as it probably is i understand what you saying but i have no idea where to begin i put your code in replace of my previous and it come up with a syntax error